# cloudfoundry JPA-2.0

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, cloud-foundry

Does CloudFoundry support JPA 2.0, other than Spring or Hibernate, as a method for accessing any of the offered databases?  If so are there any examples for how to configure this to use the database offerings?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in using JPA 2.0. Auto-reconfiguration would occur when the app is recognized as a Spring app. JPA 2.0 is a datasource so nothing prevents from the functionality changing. Unfortunately I don't think there is a example with JPA 2.0

Comment: So would the auto-reconfigure only work for a Spring app or would any persistance.xml file be recognized?

Comment: It will only work if the app is recognized or specified as Spring.